# Function to move an image when image is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html file called index.html, and it has this div in there

```
  <body>
     <div id="rock"> <img src="rock.PNG" alt="rock" onclick="test()"> </div>
     <div id="paper"> <img src="paper.PNG" alt="rock"></div>
     <div id="scissors"> <img src="scissors.PNG" alt="rock">  </div>
```

test is my function, and its within the same file and its written here

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function test(){
      var elem = document.getElementById("rock");
      var pos = 0;
      var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
      function frame() {
        if (pos == 350) {
          clearInterval(id);
        } else {
          pos++;
          elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
          elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
```

but when my page runs I click the image, and it does not move. the image is displayed, and the onclick does work (i tested it with alert) but the image won't move... any ideas?

Comment: where is react?

Comment: is the rock element in `relative` position ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the `position` attribute, likely `relative`.  You could also use `absolute` or `fixed` positioning if one of those fits your needs better.

```
#rock, #paper, #scissors {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried change the position of the elements?

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Ex:

```html
<body>
    <div id="rock" onclick="test()" style="position:absolute;"> <img src="teste.PNG" alt="rock" > </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pos = 0;
    var elem = null;
    var id = null;
    function test() {
        console.log("test");
        elem = document.getElementById("rock");
        id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    }

    function frame() {
        console.log("frame");
        if (pos == 350) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            pos++;
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
            elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a `relative` position to be able to  change `top`,`bottom`,`left`,`right` properties

```
<div id="rock" style="position: relative;"> 
   <img src="rock.PNG" alt="rock" onclick="test()"> 
</div>
```